# HTML5 Video - Fading Effects not working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I'm currently facing a strange behavior in Chrome. Basically, what I'm trying to do is, placing videos on top of other videos.

I have a basic video which is at the base layer (z-index: 0). It repeats itself all the time. When a user performs certain actions (clicking a button, etc...) another video which was invisible before clicking the button, should fade in on top of the other video.

In Firefox (fe) everything is working fine. In Chrome nothing happens. Instead of fading the top video appears instantly after the time for the fading animation ran out.

http://jsfiddle.net/J36nQ/

I set up a fiddle. As you can see, the 1000ms are running trough and after that, the top video is shown directly without fading in. Trying to do the same in Firefox will result in a successful fading animation.

That's what I tried so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Video Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0; 
        }

        .video{
            position: absolute;
        }

        #video{
            z-index: 0;
        }

        #action-1-wrapper{
            z-index: 1;
            display: none;
        }

        button{
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 10px;
        }

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){

            $action1 = $('#action-1').get(0);
            $mainVid = $('#main-video').get(0);

            $('#play1').click(function(){
                // Main Video should be paused when playing a video on top
                stopMainVideo();

                // I fade in the container which holds the video
                $('#action-1-wrapper').fadeIn(1000, function(){
                    // After fading in the video in the top wrapper should be played
                    $action1.play();                
                });
            });

            $('.actionvideo').bind('ended', function(){

                var $video = $(this).get(0);

                $video.currentTime = 0;                 
                $(this).parent().fadeOut(1000, function(){
                    playMainVideo();
                });

            });

            function stopMainVideo()
            {
                $mainVid.pause();
            }

            function playMainVideo()
            {
                $mainVid.play();
            }

        });
    </script>   
</head>
<body>
    <div id="video" class="video">
        <video autobuffer width="100%" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" id="main-video">
            <source src="https://workid-service.de/samplevids/loop.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>        
    </div>
    <div id="action-1-wrapper" class="video">
        <video autobuffer width="100%" id="action-1" class="actionvideo">
            <source src="https://workid-service.de/samplevids/aktion1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>        
    </div>
    <button id="play1">Animation 1</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope somebody can give me a hint why chrome behaves like that.

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

Comment: I tried your fiddle on chrome 30 and FF 25. I can't see any different between their..

Comment: I tried your fiddle, but my FF doesn't display mp4 at all... :/
anyway maybe you want it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/aEetJ/

Answer (score 1):

Using distinct IDs and classes where appropriate/necessary will go miles in helping you figure out the problem. I've cleaned it up in the jsfiddle provided here: http://jsfiddle.net/bas5D/2/

Instead of trying to `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` video elements, just apply a css class, make sure there's easing in place on the element, and let the CSS do the work fading the videos.

Comment: That's probably the best answer around here so take the rep :) But as I said, it won't work on my machine here because my graphics card does not support GPU acceleration. Instead of fading, the opacity is either 0 or 100

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
$("#action-1").attr("style", "");
```

to  the

```
$('#play1').click(function(){});
```

Look at [the jsfiddle i created](http://jsfiddle.net/Gzz9f/) to see it in progress.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out where this problem is coming from. Some of you do not even have the problem because video transparency on chrome only works with gpu acceleration enabled. If your computer does not support GPU acceleration opacity is just always 100%